# Does Ctrl-C (SIGINT) prevent output to be shown even if there were processes trying to output it

Tags: bash, files, rm, stdout, sigint

I had a bash script which did the wrong thing. So I pressed Ctrl-C to stop it.

Is now the output I currently see on my terminal all the output produced by the processes that have run. Are does Ctrl-C also prevent output to be printed even though the process that wanted to output something has run/finished what it was doing.

So, I do:

```
for i in *; do rm -vf $i; done
```

Can I now be sure that all `removed 'file'` messages on my screen are those that are removed and nothing more has been removed?

Maybe relevant info: I worked in a screen session over ssh.

Comment: Please show what you did, and what happened. Then proofread, and re-write, so that it makes sense to someone that does not already know what you are asking.

Comment: I gave a minimized example. Which parts do I need to clarify?

Comment: I can not tell you what to show, as I have not seen it. But with your minimal example, show what you did, what you expected, and what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially *yes*.

After the shell process catches your `Ctrl-C` interrupt, it stops it.

There are caveats however, such as in a `for` loop there can be a cmd that runs in the background.

Plus there are some cmds that run so quickly that you do not get a fast response from the shell (*especially* over a remote connection!) that it *has* or *when* it has actually received your "interruption" using Ctrl-C.